# Adding <h:form> causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: forms, session, jsf, jsf-2, illegalstateexception

I'm facing the following exception in a very simple JSF 2 page after adding `<h:form>`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2758)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2268)
```

I'm using Mojarra 2.1.3 and PrimeFaces3.0M4, on Tomcat 7.0.22 and JDK 7.

The page is a very basic data table:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>        
        <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.cars}">

                 ......
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The page shows correctly on the browser, but on the console I see the exception. The Exception does disappear if I remove the `<h:form>`.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is a known problem and has been reported by yours truly as [issue 2215](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2215). This will occur when the response buffer has overflowed (due to large content) and the response is been committed before the session is been created. This is result of bit overzealous attempts of Mojarra to postpone "unnecessary" session creation as much as possible (which is at its own a Good Thing though).

Until they get it fixed, there are several workarounds:

1. Create a `Filter` which does [`HttpServletRequest#getSession()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29) before [`FilterChain#doFilter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/FilterChain.html#doFilter%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29). Advantage: no need to change JSF configuration/code. Disadvantage: when you want to avoid unnecessary session creation yourself as well.
2. Call [`ExternalContext#getSession()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSession%28boolean%29) with `true` in bean's (post)constructor or `preRenderView` listener. Advantage: actually, nothing. Disadvantage: too hacky.
3. Add a context parameter with name of `com.sun.faces.writeStateAtFormEnd` and value of `false` to `web.xml`. Advantage: unnecessary session creation will be really avoided as opposed to #1 and #2. Disadvantage: response will now be fully buffered in memory until `</h:form>` is reached. If your forms are not extremely large, the impact should however be minimal. It would however still fail if your `<h:form>` starts relatively late in the view. This may be combined with #4.
4. Add a context parameter with name of `javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE` and a value of the Facelets response buffer size in bytes (e.g. `65535` for 64KB) so that the entire HTML output or at least the `<h:form>` (see #3) fits in the response buffer. Advantage/disadvantage, see #3.
5. Add a context parameter with name of `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` and value of `client` to `web.xml`. Advantage: session will not be created at all unless you have session scoped beans. It also immediately solves potential `ViewExpiredException` cases. Disadvantage: increased network bandwidth usage. If you're using partial state saving, then the impact should however be minimal.

As to why the problem disappears when you remove `<h:form>`, this is because no session needs to be created in order to store the view state.

---

**Update**: this has as per the duplicate [issue 2277](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2277) been fixed since Mojarra 2.1.8. So, you can also just upgrade to at least that version.

Comment: thanks!
it seems this issue will be solved with Mojarra 2.1.8 (http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2277) which should be released soon

Comment: Read through the entire JIRA it seems that the issue is still lying around, 2.1.16

Comment: I had a similar issue, and while I'm using 2.1.13, the problem was around. Implementing the #3 advice, however, resolved it.

Answer (score 6):

With the new version 2.1.21 released yesterday of javax.faces this problem seems to have disappeared.
Declare the new version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.21</version>
</dependency>
```

and replace the javax.faces.jar in the glassfish modules folder replacing the javax.faces.jar for the new version 2.1.21.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (myfaces-2.2.8 & Tomcat 8.0.23) the Problem was a typo in the `welcome-file` of `web.xml`.
While debugging i saw, that Tomcat created as expected a 404, but somehow myfaces tried to access afterwards the Session, which caused then a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed`. 
Using a valid page in `welcome-file` of `web.xml` fixed the Problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add an `<f:view>` and `</f:view>`  before and after `h:form` elements, plus add the link to you html tag for jsf tags

```html
<html xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

for this to work.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Spring MVC and call is made by Spring Forms then we should use GET method instead of POST(to fetch data) and there should be no input field we can use  intead.

Comment: <form:form method="get"
     action="#"
     id="viewAllHospital" class="validateForm"
     modelAttribute="hccHospitalUserInfoForm">
      <a href="/view/B2CSuperAdminProfileComponentController?viewAllHospital=true">View All Hospitals</a> 
     </form:form>