# getting values from primefaces components

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have facelets page and managed bean that is associated with it.
i have used primefaces components and my problem is i want to get the values selected by the user of each components when a commandbutton is clicked.
when i try to write a JoptionPane or system.out.print it does not work. i have set the commandbutton action property to btnsearchFlight method whcih is found in the managedbean. so any one what is the problem what i am missing. Or an example will be very much appreciated.

Here is the Facelets page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link href="./resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="./resources/css/cssLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>Airline Travel Planner</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h:form id="form"> 
            <div id="top">
                <ui:insert name="top">AirLine Travel Planner</ui:insert>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="left">
                    <ui:insert name="left"></ui:insert>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div id="right">
                        <ui:insert name="right"></ui:insert>
                    </div>
                    <div id="content" class="right_content" style="height: 500px">
                        <ui:insert name="content">
                            <p:selectOneRadio binding="#{calendarBean1.rdbTripType}" id="rdbTripType" value="#{calendarBean1.rdbTripType}">  
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="One Way" itemValue="1" />  
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Round Trip" itemValue="2" />  
                            </p:selectOneRadio>  
                            <br/>
                            <h:outputLabel>From:</h:outputLabel>  
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{calendarBean1.cityInfo}" style="" effect="fold" editable="true">  
                                <f:selectItems value="#{calendarBean1.cityInfo}" />  
                            </p:selectOneMenu> 
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <h:outputLabel style="position: relative">To:</h:outputLabel>
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{calendarBean1.cityInfo}" effect="fold" editable="true">  
                                <f:selectItems value="#{calendarBean1.cityInfo}" />  
                            </p:selectOneMenu> 
                            <br/><br/>
                            <h:outputLabel>Depart On:</h:outputLabel>  
                            <p:calendar value="#{calendarBean1.date3}" id="popupButtonDepartOn" showOn="button" /> 
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <h:outputLabel>Arrive On:</h:outputLabel>  
                            <p:calendar value="#{calendarBean1.date2}" id="popupButtonArriveOn" showOn="button" /> 
                            <br/>  <br/> 

                            <h:outputText value="Passenger Type" />  
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuPassengerType" binding="#{calendarBean1.selectOneMenuPassengerType}" value="#{calendarBean1.selectOneMenuPassengerType}" >  
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Adult" itemValue="1" />  
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Child" itemValue="2" />  
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Infant" itemValue="3" />  
                            </p:selectOneMenu>  
                            <br/> <br/> 
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{calendarBean1.lowestFareChecked}" />
                            <h:outputText value="Lowest Fare" />  
                            <br/> 
                            <p:commandButton  id="btnSearchFlight" value="Search"  action="#{calendarBean1.searchFlight}" > 

                            </p:commandButton>
```

Here is the managed bean class

```
package test.sample;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton;
import org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu;
import org.primefaces.component.selectoneradio.SelectOneRadio;
import storageMethods.FlightMethod;

/**
 *
 * @author Nati
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "calendarBean1")
public class CalendarBean1 implements Serializable{

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of CalendarBean1
     */
    public CalendarBean1() {
    }
    private Date date1;
    private Date date2;
    private Date date3;
    private boolean lowestFareChecked;

    public boolean isLowestFareChecked() {
        return lowestFareChecked;
    }

    public void setLowestFareChecked(boolean lowestFareChecked) {
        this.lowestFareChecked = lowestFareChecked;
    }

    public Date getDate1() {
        return date1;
    }

    public void setDate1(Date date1) {
        this.date1 = date1;
    }

    public Date getDate2() {
        return date2;
    }

    public void setDate2(Date date2) {
        this.date2 = date2;
    }

    public Date getDate3() {
        return date3;
    }

    public void setDate3(Date date3) {
        this.date3 = date3;
    }
    private SelectOneRadio rdbTripType = new SelectOneRadio();

    public SelectOneRadio getRdbTripType() {
        return rdbTripType;
    }

    public void setRdbTripType(SelectOneRadio rdbTripType) {
        this.rdbTripType = rdbTripType;
    }
    public CommandButton btnSearchFlight = new CommandButton();

    public CommandButton getBtnSearchFlight() {
        return btnSearchFlight;
    }

    public void setBtnSearchFlight(CommandButton btnSearchFlight) {
        this.btnSearchFlight = btnSearchFlight;
    }
    private SelectOneMenu selectOneMenuPassengerType = new SelectOneMenu();

    public SelectOneMenu getSelectOneMenuPassengerType() {
        return selectOneMenuPassengerType;
    }

    public void setSelectOneMenuPassengerType(SelectOneMenu selectOneMenuPassengerType) {
        this.selectOneMenuPassengerType = selectOneMenuPassengerType;
    }
    public ArrayList<SelectItem> CityInfo;

    public ArrayList<SelectItem> getCityInfo() {
        CityInfo = CityInfo();
        return CityInfo;
    }

    public void setCityInfo(ArrayList<SelectItem> CityInfo) {
        this.CityInfo = CityInfo;
    }

    public String SearchFlight() {
//        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rdbTripType.getValue().toString());
//        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,   selectOneMenuPassengerType.getValue().toString());
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,date3);
//        System.out.print("hi");
//        System.out.print(isLowestFareChecked());

        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you verify that the command button click reaches your action method? JOPtionPane in a webapp sounds strange...

Comment: Indeed, it would only execute in webserver. It won't execute in webbrowser. So this would completely fail in production setups where the webserver runs at a physically different machine than the webbrowser.

Comment: when i run the page i get the follwing exception Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed.

Comment: That's a different problem. Your form is just too large. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072311/illegalstateexception-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-response-has-been-commi

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just a typo when posting on stackoverflow, but your method is Capitalized:
 SearchFlight
And your action in .xhtml button is lowercase.
 action="#{calendarBean1.searchFlight}

Shouldn't it be

```
public String searchFlight() {
```

I never used Swing components in a JSf franework. But the system.out should work when commented out. If you method is called. Don't you get any errors in your logs?

Comment: when i run the page the following exception occured

Comment: i get the following exception Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Comment: That's a completely different problem which has already been asked and answered several times before. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072311/illegalstateexception-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-response-has-been-commi

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed webapp development (JSF) with desktop development (Swing). With JSF you don't need to  create a backing bean component for every single facelet component. You don't need

- org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton
- org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu
- org.primefaces.component.selectoneradio.SelectOneRadio

in your bean if you only want to bind the input values of these components.

Of course in some situations you will get benefits from component binding but it is not necessary in your example.

In the facelet you use the `value` attribute and the `binding` attribute, but they have the same content.

If you are only interested in input values, the `value` attribute is all you need. Let this attribute point to a backing bean field that only will hold the value, e.g. an `int` or `String`.