# Using request scoped managed bean in Primefaces JSF2.x

Tags: jsf, primefaces, scope

JSF + Primefaces newbie. (using JSF 2.1, Primefaces 3.4.2)

I have a form that has an inner panelGroup that uses a Primefaces commandButton to fetch data to populate various form components. The partialSubmit gets around the validation issues of fields not yet populated so that works well. The page functions as intended but now I'm trying to tweak the implementation to be be 'cleaner'.

My question pertains to the JSF scoping I'm using for the backing bean the form is using. Using session scope, all is well but not when using request scoping. It is my understanding that both the 'final' submit (via another p:commandButton component) and this fetch button are both invoking a submit so that the response to either constitutes the completion of the request lifecycle. If I'm correct, it explains why I get (using requst scope) the following:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

when using the fetch button.

But clearly this 'breaks' my intent for the fetch request to merely cause the form to use updated data via the bean.

So, am I correct in my understanding that any design pattern that has the use of an intermediate submission (via the partialSubmit="true" commandButton (ajax behavior is enabled by default) will require the use of at least session scoped backing beans?
Ideally, a mechanism for having an implementation request versus a navigation level request would allow for these intermediate submits to be done within the context of 1 request.
Or do I need to do some additional research? (get a JSF 2.x book rather than use my 1.2 copy?)
MTIA for any feedback.

my fetch component:

```
<p:commandButton id="returningBtn" partialSubmit="true" value="Hit if returning" 
    process="nameInfo" actionListener="#{player.loadReturning}" update="registrationForm">
    <p:resetInput target="registrationForm" />
</p:commandButton>
```

my final submit:

```
<p:commandButton tabindex="0" id="SubmitButton" value="Register"
   action="#{player.register}" update="regPage"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

> *The partialSubmit gets around the validation issues of fields not yet populated so that works well.*

No it doesn't do that. It only sends the input fields specified in `process` attribute to the server instead of *all* input fields of the current form. It's exactly the `process` attribute which tells which inputs needs to be processed (converted, validated and updated). The `partialSubmit="true"` merely reduces the network bandwidth and request parameter parsing overhead. See also [PrimeFaces blog on the subject](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1842).

---

> *The page functions as intended but now I'm trying to tweak the implementation to be be 'cleaner'. My question pertains to the JSF scoping I'm using for the backing bean the form is using. Using session scope, all is well but not when using request scoping.*

The session scope is indeed the wrong scope for forms. You need either the request or the view scope. If your form has a certain state which needs to be remembered across subsequent submits on the same form, then you need the view scope. See also [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

---

> *java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed*

This is recognizeable as a bug in Mojarra which is fixed in 2.1.8. See also [Adding <h:form> causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072311/illegalstateexception-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-response-has-been-commi) for several workarounds if you can't upgrade.

---

> *So, am I correct in my understanding that any design pattern that has the use of an intermediate submission (via the partialSubmit="true" commandButton (ajax behavior is enabled by default) will require the use of at least session scoped backing beans? Ideally, a mechanism for having an implementation request versus a navigation level request would allow for these intermediate submits to be done within the context of 1 request.*

As said, you need the view scope.

---

> *Or do I need to do some additional research? (get a JSF 2.x book rather than use my 1.2 copy?)*

Definitely. Not only is the view scope new since JSF2, but also many, many other things are done differently (read: more elegantly) in JSF2 as compared to JSF1. You can find several links to sane JSF2 resources at the bottom of [our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

Comment: Many, Many thanks for the help. My apologies, I should have been more specific with the partiaSubmit comment - indeed I use the process attribute to limit submission/validation to only those components in the nameInfo panel. The good news is I can upgrade to 2.1.8 - I'll also check out the link you provided if one cannot.  Great work on Primefaces - I'm grateful it's available.

Comment: You're welcome. Note: I'm not a PrimeFaces dev, I'm just a PrimeFaces user. OmniFaces is mine.

Comment: My mistake - I see your handle 'everywhere' with regard to many topics.  The links you provided are valuable resources - I should have utilized them first. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I hope you don't mind a quick follow-up. One benefit of using the session bean was conveying data from one view to another (2nd facelet page shows the user what was saved to the db). from your section http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters, I'm understanding that I can pass data from view 1 to view 2 by using the <f:param>, <f:viewParam> construct. Your example uses a link to pass the request parameters but I'm assuming this should work for a commandButton as well. if so, nice decoupling while keeping data passing cohesion. Wish me luck.