# p:galleria not displaying any images

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces, galleria

i am using primefaces p:galleria to display some images, however it is not displaying anything at all,

```
                <p:galleria value="#{galleriaBean.images}" 
                            var="image" 
                            effect="slide" 
                            effectSpeed="1000"
                            panelWidth="500" 
                            panelHeight="313" 
                            showCaption="false">  

                    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/Tutorial/#{image}" 
                                    alt="Image Description for #{image}" 
                                    title="#{image}"/>  
                </p:galleria>
```

GalleriaBean.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package richard.fileupload;

import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct; 
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
/**
 *
 * @author Richard
 */

@ManagedBean(name="galleriaBean")
//@RequestScoped
@ViewScoped

public class GalleriaBean {  

    public static List<String> images;  


    @PostConstruct  
    public void init() {  
        System.out.println("init called");
        images = new ArrayList<String>();  

        for(int i=1;i<=25;i++) {  
            images.add("/resources/Tutorial"+i+".jpg");
        }  
    }  

    public List<String> getImages() {  
        return images;  
    }

}
```

The images are stored in /resources/Tutorial

what am i doing wrong ? i have looked at the primefaces example and mine looks similar but nothing is displayed when run :(

i now get this massive errors :

```
INFO: init called

    WARNING: Setting non-serializable attribute value into ViewMap: (key: galleriaBean, value class: richard.fileupload.GalleriaBean)
    SEVERE: Error Rendering Vi

ew[/GUI/tutorial.xhtml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2886)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2583)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920)
        at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:155)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:175)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
        at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    INFO: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2886)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2583)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920)
        at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:155)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:175)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
        at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    WARNING: JSF1087: Unable to generate Facelets error page as the response has already been committed.
    SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    javax.faces.FacesException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
        at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:142)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2886)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2583)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920)
        at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:155)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:175)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
        at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        ... 31 more
```

but init is called :D

EDIT : got it down to 1 error now :

```
WARNING: Setting non-serializable attribute value into ViewMap: (key: galleriaBean, value class: richard.fileupload.GalleriaBean)
```

Current code : am getting no errors now but also it is not display anything

```
  /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package richard.fileupload;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct; 
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
/**
 *
 * @author Richard
 */

@ManagedBean(name="galleriaBean")
//@RequestScoped
@ViewScoped

public class GalleriaBean implements Serializable {  

    public static List<String> images;  


    @PostConstruct  
    public void init() {  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        System.out.println("init called"); //testing to see if it called, currently causing a lot of errors
        images = new ArrayList<String>();  

        for(int i=1;i<=3;i++) {  
             System.out.println("loop called"); //testing to see if it called, currently causing a lot of errors
            images.add("/resources/Tutorial/"+ i +".jpeg");
        }  
    }  

    public List<String> getImages() {  
        System.out.println("getImages called"); //testing to see if it called, currently causing a lot of errors
        return images;  
    }

}
```

the console :

```
INFO: init called
INFO: loop called
INFO: loop called
INFO: loop called
INFO: getImages called
```

all are called, but still nothing is displayed

EDIT :

Thank you for your help, i have changed the file locations as you have suggested and checked the console in chrome and you are right i get a 404 not found error, however i get this even after changing to your location,

my file directory is

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |-- GUI
 |    `-- tutorial.xhtml (page calling the images)
 |-- resources
 |    `-- Tutorial
 |         |-- Tutorial1.jpg
 |         |-- Tutorial2.jpg
 |         |-- Tutorial3.jpg
 |         :   :
 |
```

however using chromes console, i am able to see it is trying to find the images in `/fileuploadWithPreview//GUI/Tutorial/Tutorial` but they are stored in `resources/tutorial/`

The new question is how do i get it to call the resources folder outside of the GUI folder the xhtml file is in

Comment: You class `GaleriaBean` is not managed bean at all. Can you add `@ManagedBean` and `@ViewScoped` annotations on class and see what's happening?

Comment: Edited to what it is above, and still no image, but it creates the space for it

Comment: Bean can't be request scoped and view scoped at the same time!? Try to remove request scope, and add break point in `init` method to see is it executed at all.

Comment: updated original q with results

Comment: Fist make your bean serializable by implementing Serializable interface, second add this line at start of init method: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);`

Comment: OK done that, no errors now, but also no images are displayed, init is called however

Comment: All the functions are also called :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image URL is at least very strange.

Here,

```
for(int i=1;i<=25;i++) {  
    images.add("/resources/Tutorial"+i+".jpg");
}
```

you're specifying the full webcontent-relative URL.

And here,

```
<p:graphicImage value="/resources/Tutorial/#{image}" ... />
```

you're assuming the image URL to be relative to `/resources/Tutorial`.

So, your image URL ends up to be like

```
/resources/Tutorial/resources/Tutorial1.jpg
```

Two times `/resources`? This doesn't seem right. If you have paid attention to the HTTP traffic in the webbrowser's developer toolset (press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug), then you should have noticed that the browser was receiving 404 Page Not Found erros on all those images. Also, if you have paid attention to the `src` of the generated HTML `<img>` elements, you should have noticed that something's not right.

Assuming that you've the `Tutorial[n].jpg` images in the `/resources/Tutorial` folder,

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |-- resources
 |    `-- Tutorial
 |         |-- Tutorial1.jpg
 |         |-- Tutorial2.jpg
 |         |-- Tutorial3.jpg
 |         :   :
 |
 `-- page.xhtml
```

then you should be preparing the image file names as follows:

```
for(int i=1;i<=25;i++) {  
    images.add("Tutorial"+i+".jpg");
}
```

and be referencing them as follows (note: `name`, not `value`!)

```
<p:graphicImage name="Tutorial/#{image}" ... />
```

---

As to the PWC3999 exception, that concerns a completely different problem. How to solve it, look at [Adding <h:form> causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072311/illegalstateexception-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-response-has-been-commi/8072445#8072445). In other words, just upgrade Mojarra.

As to the non-serializable attribute warning, just let the mentioned class implement `Serializable`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer however The new question is how do i get it to call the resources folder outside of the GUI folder the xhtml file is in

Comment: That's already answered. Use the `name` attribute. It resolves relative to the `/resources` folder. See also among others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template/8368727#8368727

Comment: Thank you, i have tried to use `name` in `<p:graphicImage` but when i do it say the attribute is not defined in the component grpahicImage, this there anything i can do about this ?

Comment: What PF version are you using? In any case, just replace `p:` by `h:`. It definitely supports it.

Comment: Apparently they overlooked it in older versions. It's at least supported in [3.4](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/graphicImage.html).

Comment: could you answer this question? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256502/primefaces-doesnt-show-galleria-after-sign-up-but-directly-yes