# Primefaces strange error with datatable

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm developing a page which display a `datatable` same as shown in primefaces showcase.But it doesn't work like that.When i run the page with one or two rows it works but when i run the page with more than two rows server shows an error  [if i set `datatable` to `editable` then it doesn't work either].Problem solved when i set bean to `session scoped` instead `request or view`. Question is why it does not work with request or view scope?

Sources :

page :

```
                    <p:dataTable var="club" value="#{currentClubItems.clubItems}" id="clubs"
                         >

                        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{currentClubItems.onEdit}" update=":form:messages"/>

                        <p:column headerText="Main Category" style="width:15%">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{club.mainCategory}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{club.mainCategory}" editable="true">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{currentClubItems.categories}"
                                                       var="ct"
                                                       itemLabel="#{ct}"
                                                       itemValue="#{ct}"/>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>

                        <!-- other coloms-->

                        <p:column style="width:5%">
                            <p:rowEditor/>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
```

bean :

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "currentClubItems")
public class CLMItems implements Serializable {
    private List<ClubItem> clubItems;

    public CLMItems(){
        clubItems=new ArrayList<ClubItem>();

        ClubItem clubItem=new ClubItem();
        clubItem.setId("1");
        clubItem.setMainCategory("category");
        clubItem.setSubCategory("sub category");
        clubItem.setMerchant("Merchant");
        clubItem.setOffer("Content goes here..");

        //add more items......
}

//getters and setters

}
```

ClubItem :

```
public class ClubItem implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String mainCategory;
    private String subCategory;
    private String merchant;
    private String offer;

 //getters and setters

}
```

Error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2705)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2231)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:899)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: With the actual code, it's hard to get the real problem.

Comment: Ok i minimized code..

Comment: possible duplicate of [IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072311/illegalstateexception-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-response-has-been-commi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems primefaces need session has to be created if we going to add more than two rows to table.If i activate session before or in the constructor of the been then it works normally.I don't no the reason but it happens.

add

```
 //bean constructor
 public CLMItems(){
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession( true );
// other stuff
}
```

solve the problem.

Comment: There are two mainstream implementations of CDI: Seam (http://seamframework.org/Weld) and CODI (https://cwiki.apache.org/EXTCDI/). I personally prefer CODI as it provides very nice features such as Conversation scopes and the `@ViewAccessScoped` annotation. A the `@ViewAccessScoped` annotation is similar to the `@ViewScoped` annotation. However it will live as long as it is referenced from a jsf page. It means it won't be destroyed if you refresh the page and it can be passed over pages. I find that using `@ViewAccessScoped` rather that `@ViewScoped` solves many problems

Comment: Also I'm not sure it's good to mix CDI beans (`@ViewScoped` annotation) and EJBs (`@ManagedBean` annotation). You can use the `@Named` annotation which will automatically register your bean in JNDI and you will be able to access in a jsf page using it's name

Comment: I think the problem may be in one of those columns you haven't shown

Comment: @phoenix7360 `@ManagedBean` is a JSF annotation not an EJB one. Also you're mixing elements from JSF and CDI (like `@ViewScoped` from JSF only and a similar annotation that comes in MyFaces CODI for CDI). I suggest you to first learn the basics instead of misleading and confuse people (note tha OP's just using JSF and that's ok)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza components such as <p:inputText value="#{club.merchant}" style="width:100%" label="Merchant"/> for remaining bean properties