# NullPointerException while trying to access @EJB bean in managed bean constructor

Tags: jsf, constructor, nullpointerexception, ejb, managed-bean

I've an EJB service.

```
@Stateless
public class SomeService {}
```

I'd like to inject this in a viewscoped bean and initialize with it:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private SomeService someService;

    public ViewBean() {
        System.out.println(someService.getEntity());
    }

}
```

However, it throws the following exception:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: com.example.ViewBean.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:193)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    [snip]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.ViewBean.<init>(ViewBean.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
    ... 62 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words, you're expecting that EJB injection works under the covers as follows:

```
ViewBean viewBean;
viewBean.someService = new SomeService(); // EJB injected, so that constructor can access it.
viewBean = new ViewBean(); // ViewBean constructed.
```

However, this is technically impossible. It's not possible to assign an instance variable when the instance isn't been constructed at all.

The canonical approach to perform a task based on injected dependencies directly after construction is to use a [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotated method.

So, to fix your concrete problem, just replace

```
public ViewBean() {
```

by

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() { // Note: Method name is fully free to your choice.
```

This way the process would under the covers be roughly as follows:

```
ViewBean viewBean;
viewBean = new ViewBean(); // ShiftBean constructed.
viewBean.someService = new SomeService(); // EJB injected.
viewBean.init(); // PostConstruct invoked.
```

Please note that the concrete problem has completely nothing to do with the view scope. You'd have had exactly the same problem when using a request, session or application scoped bean. This is thus another evidence that you have never actually excluded it from being the cause by testing using a different scope.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation BalusC, PostConstruct worked, but I needed to mark the EJB as transient, otherwise I would get an java.io.NotSerializableException.  Most likely the cause is that EntityManager is not serializable.

I had tried PostConstruct previously and no exception is thrown if using RequestScoped. Only when using ViewScoped will you get the NotSerializableException.

Comment: This shouldn't have been mandatory. Apparently there's something more broken in your design. Which class exactly is it which is been mentioned in the `NotSerializableException` message?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. There was something more broken, so I stripped the project down to investigate and found the cause to be the context parameter javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD set to client. I had the response buffer overflow (>2KB) problem described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8072445/1754901 and used suggestion #5 which solved that problem, but now caused the NotSerializableException. So I have removed javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD, and put in place suggestion #4 instead (set to 64KB). Now all exceptions have gone and no need for transient.

Comment: Thanks BalusC.
EJB's now inject properly and can be used during Managed Bean construction via PostConstruct.

Comment: State saving method shouldn't matter for EJBs as they are injected as serializable proxies. Again, which class exactly is it which is been mentioned in the `NotSerializableException` message? Isn't it just the view scoped managed bean itself?

Comment: I have put State saving method back and the exception returns.
No class of mine is mentioned in the stack trace. Just java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.