# Pass HTTP GET parameter to a JSF bean method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i want to pass GET parameter from URL to a method, that called by clicking on button.
For example i have URL: **/someurl/semepage.xhtml?id=1**. And i have a button on my page:

```
<p:commandButton value="say it" action="#{test.sayIt(param['id'])}"/>
```

The bean looks like:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Test{
    public void sayIt(String value){
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

But when i am clicking on button, its just not react. Why is this happen ? *Method even not called.*

If i pass arguments staticaly like here:

```
<p:commandButton value="say it" action="#{test.sayIt('someword')}"/>
```

everything is ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way - using the `<f:param`, like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="Test The Magic Word" action="#{test.sayIt}">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{param['id']}"></f:param>
    <f:ajax execute="something" render="something_else"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

And in your bean

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
        .getRequest();

String id = request.getParameter("id");
```

Comment: This is works! But after i click the button, "?id=1" removes from URL in browser. But anyway, thank you!

Comment: if you don't want a full page reload -> add <f:ajax , updated my answer

Answer (score 5):

@Daniel's response is OK, but here it goes a simpler JSF 2-ish alternative for your case, using `<f:viewParam />` and EL parameter passing. Note the `<f:ajax />` is not needed in this case, as `<p:commandButton />` has ajax behaviour by default.

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" />
    </f:metadata>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="say it" action="#{bean.sayIt(id)}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    public void sayIt(String value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

}
```

*Tested with JSF 2.2.5 and Primefaces 4. Remember changing tag namespaces in case of using JSF 2.1.x.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for some reason this way is not working for me, i've mentioned it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018409/what-is-the-correct-way-to-get-parameter-from-url-in-jsf).
I am using **GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0**; **Mojarra 2.2.0**; **PrimeFaces 4.0**; **Java 1.7.0_40**.

Comment: I've tried it on tomcat server and its work! So the problem in glassfish, but i can not use tomcat for my project.

Comment: Found it ;-) And posted as an answer in your linked question. Hope you to get it working...

Comment: Easier: `#{bean.sayIt(param.id)}`

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it, have you tried `request.getParameter('id')`?