# Downloading a file from spring controllers throws IllegalStateException

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, spring-security, download, illegalstateexception

I am using the following (which looks like a lot to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers)) code to download a file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tunes/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadTune(@PathVariable(value = "file_name") String tuneId,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    perfomanceLogger.trace("=== Start retrieving tune with id: " + tuneId);
    try {
        String location = "";
        // try {
        location = resourceManagementService.getArtifcatByIdAndType(tuneId,
                ControllerConstants.TYPE_MP3);
        String pathSeparator = File.separator;

        if (location == null || location.equals("")) {// load the default
                                                        // tune
            location = System.getProperties().get("jboss.server.base.dir")
                    + pathSeparator + ServicesConstants.FILE_LOCATION
                    + pathSeparator + "ringtone_1.mp3";
            if (!new File(location).exists()) {
                location = "";
            }
        }

        if (!location.equals("")) {
            Path musicFile = Paths.get(location);
            response.setContentType("audio/wav");
            response.setContentLength((int) Files.size(musicFile));
            try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
                Files.copy(musicFile, out);
                response.flushBuffer();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.info("Could not stream tune with id: " + tuneId + " "
                        + e.getCause() + " " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | InvalidPathException | IllegalStateException e) {
        log.info("Could not stream tune with id: " + tuneId + " "
                + e.getMessage());

    }
    perfomanceLogger.trace("=== Finished retrieving tune with id: "
            + tuneId);
}
```

I am using Spring 3.2.2 and Spring Security 3.2.0.M1 and JBoss 7.1.1.Final. The problem is that some times I get an IllegalStateException. Here is the stacktrace:

```
2014-01-21 12:23:34,969 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MyWebApplication].[appServlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-80-2) Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2636) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2375) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:841) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:255) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:255) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.getSession(ServletRequestAttributes.java:79) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.setAttribute(ServletRequestAttributes.java:129) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.bind.support.DefaultSessionAttributeStore.storeAttribute(DefaultSessionAttributeStore.java:54) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.SessionAttributesHandler.storeAttributes(SessionAttributesHandler.java:123) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.updateModel(ModelFactory.java:202) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.getModelAndView(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:842) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:751) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar:3.2.0.M1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
```

Is there something wrong with the session from time to time?

Comment: I don't believe that the problem is in this piece of code. If it is working sometimes, it seems that there is a communication problem. Are you sure that the other side is working properly?

Comment: I have seen this. It has to do with Mojarra and JSF. I am not using JSF nor am I returning a view in the controller.

Comment: My previous comment was for the answer of @pbal, stack overflow decided to make it an answer after all.

Comment: @andreadi Yes it appears later when the flow has left the handler. However debugging did not help. I found a way to produce this error upon every request. I use apache HttpComponents without sending a cookie with a session id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of

```
response.flushBuffer();
```

which commits the response.

The Servlet container will take care of committing the response and flushing the `OutputStream` when it needs to.

If your file is too big, you'll want to create the session yourself before starting the download.

---

To answer comment:

It seems you never created an `HttpSession` during your request handling.

The container's implementation of `HttpServletResponse` commits the response (headers) and starts flushing the `OutputStream` when you've written X amount of bytes (configurable and depends on container). You cannot force the container to create an `HttpSession` after that's happened.

Obviously you weren't creating the `HttpSession` yourself, but Spring uses it to manage its model attributes, so it had to create it. It does that in

```
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.updateModel(ModelFactory.java:202) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
```

The simple solution is to get a reference to the `HttpServletRequest` and call its `getSession(boolean)` method, passing `true` so that it forces the creation of the `HttpSession`. **Do this anywhere before you start pushing the file.**

Comment: I have tried this as well. The error is the same, somehow the response is committed and then a session cannot be created. I could not find a way to force session creation with Spring Security but I found a work around, in a Spring interceptor I create a session by prehandling the request but I still do not get why this is happening. Could you please define "big"? The files are rather small, about 50-300 KB.

Comment: @ampofila If it does, you should be ok. If it doesn't, just do it yourself.

Comment: Yes the interceptor worked. Thank you for the prompt and helpful explanation. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar problem here: [Adding <h:form> causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072311/illegalstateexception-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-response-has-been-commi)

Comment: I have seen this. It has to do with Mojarra and JSF. I am not using JSF nor am I returning a view in the controller.